# Integer factoring, prime factors, and a Lambert series.

Tags: number-theory, prime-factorization

Apologies for the vague title, but i don't know how to give this question a proper one !

Consider the power series :
$$k_{i}(y)=\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}c_{i,m}y^{im}\;\;\;\;\;\;y\in\text{ some open disk}$$
where the numbers $c_{i,m}$ count the number of times the integer $i$ appears as a factor in the different product representations of the integer $im$ (counting multiplicity). We define $c_{1,1}=0$. For instance, $k_{1}(y)$ is given by:
$$k_{1}(y)=y^{2}+y^{3}+3y^{4}+y^{5}+3y^{6}+y^{7}+6y^{8}+3y^{9}+3y^{10}+.....$$
$k_{2}(y)$ is given by:
$$y^{2}+2y^{4}+y^{6}+4y^{8}+y^{10}+3y^{12}+....$$
Now, suppose we want to write $k_{i}(y)$ as a Lambert series:
$$k_{i}(y)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{b_{i,n}y^{in}}{1-y^{in}}$$
Where :
$$c_{i,m}=\sum_{n|m}b_{i,n}$$
Or:
$$b_{i,m}=\sum_{n|m}\mu(n)c_{i,\frac{m}{n}}$$
My questions:

1-What's the meaning/significance of the numbers $b_{i,m}$?

2-For $i=1$, and by induction, we have:
$$b_{1,m}=\binom{\Omega(m)}{\omega(m)}$$
Where $\Omega(m)$ is the number of not necessarily distinct prime factors of $m$, and $\omega(m)$ is the number of distinct prime factors of $m$. How can we prove this rigorously ?

Comment: Could you please explain, with some examples, what you mean by "the number of times the integer $i$ appears as a factor in the different product representations of the integer $im$ (counting multiplicity)"? For example, could you list the product representations of 8 that give you 6 occurrences of the number 1, and the product representations of 12 that give you 3 occurrences of the number 2, and a few more examples? I know that 8 can be written as any of the products $1\cdot8,1\cdot2\cdot4,1\cdot2\cdot2\cdot2$, and I see 3 1's and 4 2's here, not 6 1's and 4 2's as your series seem to say.

Comment: maybe the case where $i=1$ is a bit misleading. but, as you stated : $8=2.4=2.2.2$, or $8.1=1.2.1.4=1.2.1.2.1.2$. so maybe i should've said -in this case- $c_{1,m}$ counts the factors of $m$ in each product representation. in the case where $i=2$ , and $m=12$, we have: $12=2.6=3.4=3.2.2$, so 2 appears as a factor 3 times in the different representations of $12$.

Comment: Mohammad, 8 is also equal to $1\cdot2\cdot1\cdot1\cdot2\cdot2$ and $2\cdot1\cdot2\cdot1\cdot2$. How are you deciding when and where factors of 1 are included in the products you write down?

Comment: exactly !! that's why i said it is misleading in this case ! but in order for the definition of $c_{i,m}$ to be consistent we have to pick a convention ! i am still struggling with a better way to define $c_{i,m}$. Do you have any suggestions !?

Comment: Sorry, I don't have any suggestions, because I don't know what you're counting! If you provided more examples, I might have a guess, at least...

Comment: lets begin with $i=1$. $c_{1,m}=1$ for all $m$ is a prime. $c_{1,m}=2$ for all $m$ is a semi-prime. for $8=2.4=2.2.2$ we have 6 factors appearing in the three representations. for $12=2.6=3.4=2.2.3$ we have 8 factors appearing in the four representations. for $i=2$, $c_{2,m}=1$ for all $m=2r$, and $r$ is odd. for $m=4$, we have $4=2.2$, so we have two 2's appearing in the two different representation. for $m=8$, we have $8=2.4=2.2.2$, so we have four 2's appearing the three different representations. for $m=12$, we have $12=2.6=3.4=2.2.3$, so we have three 2's appearing the trepresentations.

Comment: Ok, I think I understand what $c_{i,m}$ is for $i>1$, but it's not true that $c_{2,m}=1$ for all $m=2({\textrm{odd}})$, since $30=2\cdot15=2\cdot3\cdot5$, for example. I still don't know what $c_{1,m}$ counts. I'll leave you with a final thought - your sequence $c_{1,m}$ (what's given in your polynomial) is https://oeis.org/A066637 , and $c_{2,m}$ doesn't seem to be in OEIS.